# How to change local ip to server ip in order to use Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, ubuntu, digital-ocean

Yesterday, I registered a new account at digitalocean.com in order to use a server. What I want to do is use Node.js for testing purposes. So I made a new droplet with the Ubuntu OS and later on, I used FileZilla to find the www file and upload html, js, css with node_modules files/folders. I installed node package manager, mongodb, mongoose and express. But the problem for now is socket.io can't be found. I changed local ip

```
http://127.0.0.x./socket.io/socket.io.js
```

to

```
http://178.62.220.194/node_modules/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

I will upload more info soon. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: missing `.` near `220.194`

Comment: I had to remove that dot because I can not use full ip adress in the question... Forgot to mention that..

Comment: Are you sure your `node_modules` is accessible directly?

Comment: It has to be. I will test it out tonight.

Comment: Do not try to serve it from `node_modules`. Follow the socket.io getting started guide http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: I changed it to /socket.io/socket.io.js, but no results.